# Reducir tiempo de reporte Excel openpyxl

Tags: python, django

Saludos tengo un reporte que obtengo con un total de registros de 1197 , cada registro posee 15 campos, este reporte se toma un tiempo promedio de 10 segundos, deseo saber si existe forma de reducir el mismo, los datos los tengo de una sola tabla o model(personal_personal), adjunto mi codigo:

```
 # Consultar Personal
    personal_list = list(Personal.objects.all())

    # ESTABLECER BORDES
    thin_border = Border(
        left=Side(style='thin'), right=Side(style='thin'),
        top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin')
    )

    # Creamos el libro de trabajo
    wb = Workbook()

    # Definimos como nuestra hoja de trabajo, la hoja activa, por defecto la primera del libro
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Nomina"
    # En la celda B1 ponemos el texto 'REPORTE DE PERSONAS'
    ws.merge_cells('B2:I2')
    ws['B2'] = 'Listado en Nomina'
    ws['B2'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    # ws.cell(row=2, column=2).border = thin_border
    b2 = ws['B2']
    b2.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)
    # Creamos los encabezados desde la celda B3 hasta la E3
    ws['B3'] = '#'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=2).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=2).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    b3 = ws['B3']
    b3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['C3'] = 'Nombre'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=3).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=3).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    c3 = ws['C3']
    c3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['D3'] = 'Cedula'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=4).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=4).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    d3 = ws['D3']
    d3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['E3'] = 'Telefono'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=5).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=5).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    e3 = ws['E3']
    e3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['F3'] = 'Celular'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=6).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=6).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    f3 = ws['F3']
    f3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['G3'] = 'Correo'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=7).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=7).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    g3 = ws['G3']
    g3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['H3'] = 'Cargo'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=8).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=8).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    h3 = ws['H3']
    h3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['I3'] = 'Area'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=9).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=9).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    i3 = ws['I3']
    i3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['J3'] = 'Fec. Ingreso'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=10).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=10).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    j3 = ws['J3']
    j3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['K3'] = 'Fec. Salida'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=11).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=11).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    k3 = ws['K3']
    k3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['L3'] = 'Tipo Sangre'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=12).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=12).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    l3 = ws['L3']
    l3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['M3'] = 'Sueldo'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=13).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=13).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    m3 = ws['M3']
    m3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['N3'] = 'Cargas'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=14).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=14).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    n3 = ws['N3']
    n3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['O3'] = 'Nro. Cta.'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=15).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=15).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    o3 = ws['O3']
    o3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['P3'] = 'Estado Civil'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=16).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=16).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    p3 = ws['P3']
    p3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    ws['Q3'] = 'Direccion'
    ws.cell(row=3, column=17).border = thin_border
    ws.cell(row=3, column=17).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    q3 = ws['Q3']
    q3.font = Font(bold=True, color=colors.DARKBLUE, size=12)

    cont = 4
    indice = 1
    for personal in personal_list:

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=2).value = indice
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=2).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=2).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=3).value = personal.nombre
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=3).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=3).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=4).value = personal.cedula
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=4).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=4).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion
        if personal.telefono:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=5).value = personal.telefono
        else:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=5).value = '---'
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=5).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=5).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=6).value = personal.celular
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=6).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=6).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        # agregamos la data, borde, alineacion
        if personal.correo:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=7).value = personal.correo
        else:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=7).value = '--'
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=7).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=7).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=8).value = personal.cargo.nombre
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=8).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=8).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=9).value = personal.area.nombre
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=9).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=9).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=10).value = personal.fec_ingreso
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=10).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=10).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=11).value = personal.fec_salida
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=11).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=11).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=12).value = personal.tipo_sangre
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=12).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=12).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=13).value = str(personal.sueldo)
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=13).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=13).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=14).value = personal.cargas_familiares
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=14).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=14).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=15).value = personal.cta_banco
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=15).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=15).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        if personal.estado_civil == 1:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).value = 'Soltero(a)'
        elif personal.estado_civil == 2:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).value = 'Casado(a)'
        elif personal.estado_civil == 3:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).value = 'Divorciado(a)'
        elif personal.estado_civil == 4:
            ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).value = 'Viudo(a)'
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=16).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        ws.cell(row=cont, column=17).value = personal.direccion
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=17).border = thin_border
        ws.cell(row=cont, column=17).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

        cont = cont + 1
        indice = indice + 1

    # Establecemos el nombre del archivo
    nombre_archivo = "nomina.xlsx"

    # Definimos que el tipo de respuesta
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/ms-excel")
    contenido = "attachment; filename={0}".format(nombre_archivo)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = contenido

    # ESTABLECER DIMENSIONES A COLUMNAS
    ws.column_dimensions["A"].width = 10.0
    ws.column_dimensions["C"].width = 40.0
    ws.column_dimensions["D"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["E"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["F"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["G"].width = 40.0
    ws.column_dimensions["H"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["I"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["J"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["K"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["L"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["M"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["N"].width = 10.0
    ws.column_dimensions["O"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["P"].width = 20.0
    ws.column_dimensions["Q"].width = 50.0

    wb.save(response)
    # retorna el archivo excel
    return response
```

**Edicion:**

Aqui adjunto mis modelos relacionados entre si:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.IntegerField(
        choices=estado_choices,
        default=Activo,
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Cargo(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    estado = models.IntegerField(
        choices=estado_choices,
        default=Activo,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Horario(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hora_ingreso = models.TimeField()
    hora_salida = models.TimeField()
    estado = models.IntegerField(
        choices=estado_choices,
        default=Activo,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Personal(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imagen = models.FileField(upload_to='nomina/', null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fec_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True)
    fec_ingreso = models.DateField(null=True)
    fec_salida = models.DateField(null=True)
    cta_banco = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    tipo_sangre = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    horario = models.ForeignKey(Horario, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    cargas_familiares = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sueldo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    estado_civil = models.IntegerField(        
        choices=estadocivil_choices,
        null=True
    )
    estado = models.IntegerField(
        choices=estado_choices,
        default=Activo,
    )
    cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fondos_reserva = models.IntegerField(
        choices=fondosReserva_choices,
        default=Mensual,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Donde una persona tiene un area, un cargo un horario.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: Por si acaso tienes el django-toolbar ?

Comment: Saludos uso pycharm y he verificado que en el Query Django se toma 1 segundo maximo, donde tarda mas es en armar los estilos, bordes etc...

Comment: removiendo estilos se reduce el tiempo a 5 seg.

Comment: Por eso al usar el debug django-ToolBar puedes fijarte que puedes estar haciendo una consulta mala.   & yo creo que 5 segundo es demasiado.

Comment: Diego, puedes mostrar tu modelo. Se me ocurre que puedes optimizar el query.

Comment: @César gracias, ya agrego mi  model..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez no resuelva directamente tu problema ya que no he usado openpyxl antes, pero esto definitivamente tiene que reducir el tiempo de tu query.

Cuando usas:

```
Personal.objects.all()
```

Y luego en tu código llamas a otros campos referenciados como:

```
personal.area.nombre
personal.cargo.nombre
```

Estás generando un query adicional por cada una de estas relaciones. En cambio, si haces uso de [`QuerySet.select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), lo que va a hacer Django internamente es hacer JOINs a nivel de base de datos para extraer los registros. Claro, esto hace que se convierta en un solo query más complejo pero a la vez mucho más eficiente.

Intenta cambiando esta parte de tu código:

```
personal_list = list(Personal.objects.all())
```

A algo como esto:

```
personal_list = list(Personal.objects.all().select_related('area', 'cargo'))
```

Me comentas cómo te va.

Comment: Genial, pude reducir el tiempo de 5 segundos a 2 segundos, desconocia sobre que ejecutaba consulta extra cuando tenia relaciones...

Comment: Estoy planteando en Meta que todas las preguntas de Python muestren una sugerencia para que los usuarios etiqueten de forma más preciso. ¿Podrías darle un vistazo? [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83). Tu opinión sería interesante pues eres de los más reputados en esta etiqueta. ¡Gracias!